# Design alternative for objects with mutually exclusive data members

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++14

It was tough to summarize the problem in the title; so allow me to clarify the situation here.

I have a class that I'm designing that represents a [BER TLV structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#BER_encoding). In this specification, the "data" portion of the TLV can contain raw bytes of data OR other nested TLVs. To support both forms, I use the same structure but with two vectors (only one will actually contain something, depending on what we find as we parse the TLV data):

```
class BerTlv
{
public:

    void Parse(std::vector<std::uint8_t> const& bytes_to_parse);

    // Assume relevant accessors are provided

private:

    // Will be m_data or m_nestedTlvs, but never both
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> m_data;
    std::vector<BerTlv> m_nestedTlvs;
};
```

From the outside, after this object is fully constructed (all TLV data parsed), the user will need to detect what kind of data they are dealing with. Basically, they'd have to check `m_data.empty()`, and if so, use `m_nestedTlvs`. I'm not really happy with this approach; it smells like it lacks a better design.

I thought of some form of a union, although I do not think a real union would be appropriate here since vector data is heap allocated. So I thought of `std::variant`:

```
std::vector<std::variant<BerTlv, std::uint8_t>> m_data;
```

However, I'm worried this negatively impacts the `std::uint8_t` case since that's literally just byte data. It will now become non-continuous as well. The variant only benefits the nested TLV case and not by much.

Next I considered using the visitor pattern here, but I can't quite visualize what the interface would look like or how this would improve usability in both cases (raw data vs nested TLVs). Is visitor the right solution here?

Nothing I've thought of so far feels right, so I'm hoping for feedback on a better design approach to this problem. The general problem here is having data members that are sometimes unused or are mutually exclusive. It's a problem I run into in other contexts as well, so it would be great to have a general design approach to such a problem.

Note that I have access to C++14 features and below.

Comment: Instead of having two different vectors of values, have you considered using a single vector of bytes, plus a tree that references portions of the vector?

Comment: @VaughnCato: You mean a tree that refers to offsets in the vector? I don't see how that could work when you end up with a complex tree of nested TLVs. Part of the responsibility of this class is to abstract away "array of bytes" from the user and provide complete, usable types and objects. Also want to avoid parsing post-construction.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong with a union   union { 
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> m_data; 
    std::vector<BerTlv> m_nestedTlvs; 
  } content; and remembering ths actual type in an enum outside of the enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, they'd have to check m_data.empty(), and if so, use m_nestedTlvs.

If the idea is that an object either has an array of bytes or has an array of other objects, then that's the variant you ought to use: `variant<vector<std::uint8_t>, vector<BerTlv>>`. A `vector` of `variant`s does not match your specified use case.

Comment: I made a false assumption that `variant` was provided with C++14 but it was not. It's part of C++17. So I guess variant is out of the question.

Comment: `boost::variant`?

Comment: @void.pointer: There are also plenty of implementations of `variant` out there besides Boost's.

Comment: @NicolBolas Such as?